# NoMethodError from serialization in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I'm trying to create an application that has forms, who have questions, who, in turn have answers. The questions require a different type of answer, e.g. free text or a choice from a set of possible choices (multiple choice question). Different types of questions inherit from the base class Question. It's the multiple choice questions that are proving problematic.

There are going to be multiple choice questions with different sets of possible answers (say, 1-5, 1-8 or yes/no). I was thinking of creating a class MultipleChoiceQuestion < Question, and the answer choices are given as an array and then saved to the database using serialization. I am, however, unable to get the serialization working at all.

From googling around, I've figures that serialization should work by writing:

```
class MultipleChoiceQuestion < Question
    serialize :choices, Array
end
```

Now if I open rails console, and type

```
  q1 = MultipleChoiceQuestion.new
  q1.choices
```

I only get a NoMethodError on choices. Is there something else I need to do to get serialization working? I've also tried adding a text column "choices" in the database by editing the migration file and migrating the database, but it doesn't help either.

I'm using Rails 3.2.6 and PostgreSQL 9.1.

**Update:** If I change the MultipleChoiceQuestion class to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base instead of Question, serialization works. But Question inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, so I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Is `Question` extending `ActiveRecord::Base` ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :preferences, Hash
end

def preferences
 read_attribute(:preferences) || write_attribute(:preferences, {})
end
```

to ensure that its default vaue is what you expected. And I mark the column of type text that is being serialized so attribute is stored as yaml.

```
user.preferences[:key]  = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a new model (and some database tables) for the choices, e.g.:

```rb
class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :multiple_choice_question
end

class MultipleChoiceQuestion < Question
    has_many :choices
end
```